# Resize vdi size doesn't work as supposed

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, virtualbox, size

I just installed the new one Debian xfce via VirtualBox, but decided to increase the vdi size from 8GB to 20GB (because it requires 42% of all disk space at this moment):

> VBoxManage.exe modifyhd debian.vdi --resize 20000

VirtualBox Manager tells me that debian.vdi now has 20GB as supposed, but when I started Debian, the df output tells me that it has 8GB as earlier. Why?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. The dup linked is using GParted to resize a disk. This is doing a resize using VirtualBox. Though related, they're subtly linked.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48322/virtualbox-os-cannot-use-the-new-extended-disk-space-vdi if you aren't using LVM, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/fix-the-virtualbox-centos-after-vdi-resizing-or-expand-a-lv-group if you're using LVM.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to resize the filesystem with resize2fs
For example:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

/edit:

@Stephane Chazelas is correct. You need to resize the partition first. Then resize the filesystem. If you use lvm it's failry simple. Create a new partition with fdisk on the new empty space, use lvm type (8e). Then create a physical volume on that new partition with

`pvcreate <path_to_new_disk>`

Then add the new physical volume to the volume group (use `vgs` to see a summary of volume groups):

`vgextend <volumegroup_name> /path_to_new_disk`

Then you can extend the lv (run `lvs` to see a list of logical volumes):
`lvextend <path_to_current_logical_volume> <path_to_new_physical_volume>`

For example. If the current disk that you whant to resize is /dev/sda1 and the new space is on /dev/sda2 (where volgroup is the volume group name):

```
pvcreate /dev/sda2
vgextend volgroup /dev/sda2
lvextend /dev/volume_group_name/logical_volume_name /dev/sda2
```

Now the partition is resized, the next step is to resize the filesystem with resize2fs:

`resize2fs /dev/volume_group_name/logical_volume_name>`

Comment: You need to resize the partition first. (and if there's a /dev/sda2, you also need to move it beforehand).

Comment: @mwolf resize2fs says that there's nothing to do

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish the disk space and the size of the partition.

If you resize a `vdi` it means you enlarge your physical disk but in the virtual OS Debian, as long as you do not resize the logical partition then your OS will not be able to write on the new physical space available.

To accomplish such a task, you can use the binary `resize2fs` [see the man to identify your needs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) or if you don't feel comfortable with command line you can download `gparted` bootable iso and use `gparted` (which is graphical) by booting on the `iso` to resize easily your Debian partition.

The question has already been answer several time :

- Ask Ubuntu "[How do I repartition with GParted? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/q/51272/93232)" which was a duplicate from "[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)"
- see also this post from U&L Q&A titled: "[Resize partitions with gparted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83313/53092)"

Comment: resize2fs says that there's nothing to do

Comment: We can't type the correct command line without knowing your partition table. You should try gparted, it would be easier for you.  Also you can take a look here ==> http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83313/53092

Comment: I can't resize/move the /dev/sda1 because it's in use

Comment: You should use gparted and boot on the gparted live linux or even on ubuntu live cd (which has gparted in it) . you nnet to unmount your partition before being able to modify it. (that's why it's easier to do it from a live cd

Comment: see also here ==> http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted

Comment: @Kiwy - couple of comments. When linking to other Q&A, it's helpful to include the title rather than just "here". Also it's perfectly OK to have duplicate content on the various SE sites. It' preferred if you bring the relevant pieces from those other sites into an A here.